# Open website by clicking on button without reloading the whole page (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to make a button (Radio, Button or Checkbox) on my website to let the user to redirect to other page without reloading the whole page, I am not a Pro in this but I have little knowledge of AJAX and only thing I know is that this can be done by replacing the existing "div" contents. Let me explain what I want to achieve here: "Let's say I have a three radio buttons on my website with the labels (Google, YouTube & Facebook) All I want to do is when user clicks on Google button it should display the Google homepage by staying on the same page without reloading the page and Google website should be opened below the radio buttons and rest of the buttons should do the same."

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <style>
        .test1 {  
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;  
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input").click(function(){
                $("#test").load(location.href = "https://www.google.com");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div>
        <center><p><strong>Websites:</strong>
            <input type="radio" id="google" name="web">
            <label for="google">Google</label>
            <input type="radio" id="youtube" name="web">
            <label for="youtube">YouTube</label>
            <input type="radio" id="fb" name="web">
            <label for="fb">Facebook</label></p></center>
    </div>
    <div id="test" class="test1">
        //Websites should be loaded here//
    </div>
</html>
```

Experts opinions are required, Examples or Demo are highly appreciated :-)

Update: I have added my code that I am currently working on, Currently by clicking on any radio button it will be display the Google homepage but not dynamically because I don't know how to make it work in AJAX.

Comment: use `<iframe />`?

Comment: @CodeSpirit I cannot use <iframe /> for this as it creates popups. Creating and replacing <div> is what I want to achieve.

Comment: @HassaanIqbal Obviously this is not possible because youtube google and facebook are not only html code but javascript apps and all requests from your domain will be blocked by their servers (and your browser) because of CORS so iFrame is the only solution if you want to display a website inside another. Also why should this create popups?

Comment: @CodeSpirit May be you are right, Google and other websites are not only developed with HTML in fact they are developed with the combination of numerous languages. But may be I can open the HTML based websites?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, i looked into it for you

The only way to do this this would be by using an iframe, however, all of the above website have a feature known as CORS that checks if the website is being loaded from the parent domain or on another parent domain. Thus, for this does not seem do-able!

*UPDATE*

Here is a very basic example (very basic JS) as per requested in the comments. Hope the idea is understandable!

```js
 window.addEventListener('load', one);
    document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", one);
    document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", two);
    document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", three);


    function one() {
        ['example2', 'example3'].forEach(function(id) {

            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("example1").style.display = "block";

        });

    }

    function two() {
        ['example1', 'example3'].forEach(function(id) {

            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("example2").style.display = "block";

        });

    }

    function three() {
        ['example1', 'example2'].forEach(function(id) {

            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("example3").style.display = "block";

        });
    }
```

```css
   .iframe {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 85vh;
        }
```

```html
     <title>Example</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <nav class="mt-3 mx-3 text-center">
        <li class="row">
            <ul class="col-md"><button id="one">Example 1</button></ul>
            <ul class="col-md"><button id="two">Example 2</button></ul>
            <ul class="col-md"><button id="three">Example 3</button></ul>
        </li>
    </nav>
    <div id="example1">
        <p>Page 1</p>
        <iframe src="https://example.com" class="iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="example2">
        <p>Page 2</p>
        <iframe src="https://example.com" class="iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="example3">
        <p>Page 3</p>
        <iframe src="https://example.com" class="iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What if I want to load other websites that doesn't have the CORS feature?

Comment: That is for sure possible with Ajax and iframes. Do you want me to add to my answer?

Comment: Sure, Why not? Please share your experience with us :-)

Comment: Check what I added

Comment: If this helped at all, please mark it as answered!